# JQGrid ToolTip, length of time it displays

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

JQgrid has a tooltip built in that when the user hovers over a cell, the contents of that cell appear in the tool tip. we are using this for cells that contain large amounts of text.

The only problem is, is that the tool tip only appears for about 5 seconds, and then disappears. Is there a way to make this tool tip appear until the mouse is moved, or at least a longer length of time?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably there are a simple way using CSS or JavaScript technique, but I din't know this. What is definitively possible is to use some Tooltip plugin to implement the behavior which you want. In [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656980/external-tooltip-plug-in-on-jqgrid/4658572#4658572) for example I included [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jQueryUiTooltop.htm) which use [jQuery UI Tooltip](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138112/Tooltip) which will be released in th next version (1.9) of jQuery UI. You can start to use [jQuery UI Tooltips](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tooltip) already now.

You have many settings to customize Tooltips. It can look not so erotically like on [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jQueryUiTooltop.htm). In the demo I wanted to show only, that new Tooltips can display HTML code and not only the text. Only because of that I made tolltips on the demo in color and with the `"<hr />"` element in inside the displayed text.

Comment: Great thank you, I will look at that and see if I can get it to work for me.

Comment: @twaldron: You are welcome! Just get the demo and try to modify for your data. It you will have additional questions you can ask me.